# Unable to use ngForm in angular 4 - getting undefined error

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 and have forms on the page. I want to use form.valid property to enable/disable the submit button. Below is my code. But it errors out stating property 'valid' of undefined .
I have imported FromsModule and provided it in app.module.ts .
What am I missing?

component HTML

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form #dForm = "ngForm">
                    <fieldset [disabled]="!(devAuthEditable)"> 
                  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                          <tr> 
  .....
  .....
  .....
<input  type="button" (click)="submitMajorVersionChanges()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="dForm.form.invalid" >
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `dForm.invalid`. You should remove `form`

Comment: did - same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  **`!dForm.form.valid`**,

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #dForm="ngForm">
  {{ heroForm.form.valid }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!dForm.form.valid">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: He uses `ngForm`, so no need to define `FormGroup`

Comment: @hgiasac yes updated :) anyways the answer is above as mentioned

Comment: changed it to dForm.invalid - still the same error .

Comment: @xan_z try with !dForm.form.valid

Comment: same error - dForm.form.invalid and dForm.invalid - both error out with same error - invalid on undefined.

Comment: Can you try it? i am using the same code which works

Comment: did it help to sort your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`[disabled]="dForm.invalid"` 
or 
`[disabled]="!dForm.valid"`